# Go pointer subtraction

Tags: go, pointers, hex

When I run this program it looks like the value of the two pointers is 16 bytes (x’10”) bytes apart but how can that be if the first string is over 16 bytes long? Or am I looking at this incorrectly?

```
package main

import (
"fmt"   
    "math"
    
)

func main() {
fmt.Println("Hello,       playground")  
    x := "string                   4"

    xx := "string2"

    y := "string3"

    xptr := &x
    fmt.Println(xptr)     
    fmt.Println(*xptr)
   
    xxptr := &xx
    fmt.Println(xxptr)     
    fmt.Println(*xxptr)

    fmt.Println("hey")
    fmt.Println("hey")
    fmt.Println("hey")
    fmt.Println("hhey")
    fmt.Println("hey")
   
    yptr := &y
    fmt.Println(yptr, *yptr) 

    xxx := math.Pow(2,3) 
    fmt.Printf("%.6f",xxx)
```

}

Comment: string variables do not contain the textual data of the string.

Answer (score 3):

The program prints the addresses of the string variables, not the address of the array of bytes backing the strings.  A string variable contains a pointer to the string data and the string length. The structure of a string variable is reflected in the [reflect.StringHeader](https://godoc.org/reflect#StringHeader) type:

```
type StringHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
}
```

See [Go Data Structures](https://research.swtch.com/godata) for a detailed description of the string memory layout in Go.

On a 64-bit architecture, the size of a string variable is 16 bytes.

Use the [unsafe package](https://godoc.org/unsafe) to extract the pointer to the string data:

```
xh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&x))
xxh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&xx))

fmt.Printf("0x%x %d\n", xh.Data, xh.Len)   // prints 0x4c0648 26
fmt.Printf("0x%x %d\n", xxh.Data, xxh.Len) // prints 0x4bcfd4 7
```

Comment: Interesting- I thought it must be something like that. I will have to review.